# pivot_longer with groups of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
df_start <- tribble(
    ~name,   ~age, ~x1_sn_ctrl1, ~x1_listing2_2, ~x1_affect1, ~x2_sn_ctrl1, ~x1_listing2_2, ~x2_affect1, ~number,
    "John",   28,        1,            1,             9,           4,            5,                9,       6,
    "Paul",   27,        2,            1,             4,           1,            3,                3,       4,
    "Ringo",  31,        3,            1,             2,           2,            5,                8,       9)
```

I need to `pivot_longer()` while handling the groupings within my columns:

- There are 2 x-values (1 and 2)
- There are 3 questions (sn_ctrl1, listing2_2, affect1) for each x-value

In my actual dataset, there are 14 x's.

**Essentially, what I'd like to do is to apply `pivot_longer()` to the x-values but leave my 3 questions (sn_ctrl1, listing2_2, affect1) wide.**

What I'd like to end up with is this:

```
df_end <- tribble(
    ~name, ~age, ~xval, ~sn_ctrl1, ~listing2_2, ~affect1, ~number,
    "John", 28,    1,        1,         1,          9,       6,
    "John", 28,    2,        4,         5,          9,       6,
    "Paul", 27,    1,        2,         1,          4,       4,  
    "Paul", 27,    2,        1,         3,          3,       4, 
    "Ringo", 31,   1,        3,         1,          2,       9, 
    "Ringo", 31,   2,        2,         5,          8,       9)
```

I have tried **lots** of very unsuccessful attempts playing with regex in `names_pattern` & `pivot_longer` but am completely striking out.

Anyone know how to tackle this?

THANKS!

PS: Note that I tried to make a straightforward reproducible example. The actual names of my columns vary slightly. For instance, there is `x1_sn_ctrl1` & `x1_attr1_ctrl2`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df_start, 
                    cols = -c(name, age, number), 
                    names_to = c("xval", ".value"),
                    names_pattern = 'x(\\d+)_(.*)')
```

Which yields

```
# A tibble: 9 x 7
  name    age number xval  sn_ctrl1 listing2_2 affect1
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 John     28      6 1            1          1       9
2 John     28      6 2            4         NA       9
3 John     28      6 1           NA          5      NA
4 Paul     27      4 1            2          1       4
5 Paul     27      4 2            1         NA       3
6 Paul     27      4 1           NA          3      NA
7 Ringo    31      9 1            3          1       2
8 Ringo    31      9 2            2         NA       8
9 Ringo    31      9 1           NA          5      NA
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so, so much @Ronak! So fast, clever, helpful.

Comment: I've made a slight edit to the column name in `df_start` above to reflect my actual situation--the format of the column names is actually varied (similar to how it is in the repro above). 

Because the format isn't identical for all columns, the `names_pattern` argument you offered doesn't work.

I tried changing `names_pattern` as you have it to `names_sep = "_"`, which I thought would've worked but doesn't seem to interact with having only 2 arguments in the `names_to` parameter. 

Any suggestion of how to fix this? Sorry to have you double-work. I tried to solve it first!

Comment: @wscampbell you can use `tidyr::pivot_longer(df_start, 
                    cols = -c(name, age, number), 
                    names_to = c("xval", ".value"),
                    names_pattern = 'x(\\d)_(.*)')` but since the column names becomes duplicate it creates a `.copy` variable. Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: That solved it! Perfect! There are no repeating column names, so `.copy` isn't being created. You nailed it! Thanks once again, @Ronak!

Comment: I took the liberty to update the answer so that it works with the current state of the question. Cheers @RonakShah